# Arrays as properties - retain, etc

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsarray, retain

I'm beginning to get my head round all the memory management stuff, but I'm a bit puzzled by the use of properties with arrays. If I declare the property in the interface like so -

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

then synthesize it in the implementation, do I need to alloc it when I create the array? Like so -

```
self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

or does this result in an extra retain count? Should I just do -

```
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and let the setter do the retaining?

Many thanks to anyone who can clarify this for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases you are letting the setter retain your instance.

#### In this case you are overretaining:

```
self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The setter does and the alloc message sent.

This can be fixed with:

```
self.myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *newInstance = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.myArray = newInstance;
[newInstance release];
```

#### This is fine

```
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

however not every class has a convenience class method to return an autoreleased instance.

Have a look at the [Memory Management Programming Guide / Object Ownership and Disposal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB), this will give you a good understanding about when the retain counts increases and when you should release.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I'd forgotten about the autorelease way of doing it, though I used to do it when I copied code directly from examples. On the positive side, I think I must be getting a more basic understanding of what's happening to actually realise there was an issue! I'll re-read the guide, it might mean something to me now...

Comment: @Franklyn Weber you are welcome. **Don't** rely on the retainCount property of objects if you like to debug your code. The link to the guide say the most, it's all about when to release: only if you claimed ownership of an instance.